# AASM: Transitions to a 2 different states depending on conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aasm

I am using AASM. Is it possible 2 different states depending on conditions For example:

```
aasm_event :completes do
  transitions :to => condition? ? :complete : :terminate, 
              :from => [:active]
end
```

the purpose of this is because I'm using legacy code and there are a lot of "completes" calls and the terminate status is new.

I already try override in a new file the state machine as

```
aasm_event :completes do
  transitions :to => :terminate, 
              :from => [:active]
end
```

but it didn't work, it still goes to complete state

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For this you can set up a [**guard**](https://github.com/aasm/aasm#guards) per transition, which will run before actually running the transition:

```
aasm_event :completes do
  transitions :from => [:active], :to => :complete, :guard => :condition?
  transitions :from => [:active], :to => :terminate 
end

def condition?
  some_contition
end
```

This will transition to `:complete` if `:condition?` is true, otherwise it will transition to `:terminate`.